# How to map PCI / PCIe virtual to physical memory in VxWorks 7.0?

Tags: vxworks

Well, I am trying to write a device driver for PCI express (any PCI solutions will be great as well). After digging into the WindRiver documentation, ever for other VxWorks versions, could not find any solution for mapping virtual to physical address.
Looking for something similar to Linux's mmap(..) commands.
Code will be appreciated as well..

Cheers,
Lamy

Answer (score 1):

In VxWorks 7, the preferred method is to implement a vxbus device driver.  Within the driver you will have a section of code that looks roughly like this; depending on how many PCI base address registers you are interested in.

```
for (i = 0; i < VXB_MAXBARS; i++)
    {
    pRes = vxbResourceAlloc (pDev, VXB_RES_MEMORY, i);
    if (pRes != NULL)
        {
        pResAdr = (VXB_RESOURCE_ADR *)pRes->pRes;
        if (pResAdr != NULL)
            {
            pDrvCtrl->resource[i].handle = pResAdr->pHandle;
            pDrvCtrl->resource[i].base = (void *)pResAdr->virtual;
            pDrvCtrl->resource[i].res = pRes;
            break;
            }
        else
            {
            (void) vxbResourceFree (pDev, pRes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Later, you would use vxbRead32 and/or vxbWrite32 with the resource[i].handle and pDrvCtrl->resource[i].base parameters for indicating which base address resource you are interested in accessing and the architecture specific path/mechanism for accessing the resource.

Normally, you are not concerned with the actual value of the virtual address, but the virtual address can be known by inspecting the members of the VXB_RESOURCE_ADR data structure.  In this example, pDrvCtrl->resource[i].base contains the virtual address value.

The net result is that vxbResourceAlloc automatically takes care of the architecture/board specific mapping of physical to virtual address and keeps track of the values for you.

Answer (score 0):

`vxbPciAutoConfig` reads PCI parameters which hwconf.c provides.
Search PCI_MEM_ADRS, PCI_MEMIO_ADRS, PCI_IO_ADRS in hwconf.c and config.h under your BSP.  `-> pciDeviceShow` and `-> pciHeaderShow` show PCI configuration.